# Cannon.js lock constraint for two overlapping bodies without explosion

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I created two boxes and want to set a lock constraint but two boxes are overlapping.

How can I set that without explosion with cannon.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var c = new CANNON.LockConstraint(bodyA, bodyB, {
         maxForce: params.maxForce || Number.MAX_VALUE
      });
      c.collideConnected = false;
      this.world.addConstraint(c);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works.

By the way, do you know how can we put two bodies overlap without using constraints and without using group collision?

Comment: To ignore the collisions the only callback i know is `collide` callback.
You can try using `CollisionFilterMask` and `collisionfiltergroup`.
Read [this](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/master/demos/collisionFilter.html). Its easy to understand.

Comment: Hi Huzaifa, the lock example: https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/constraints.html, I see that there is a vibration of blocks when collision. Do you know how can we make locked constraint blocks become a rigid body?